# Check if variable is fill and pass it into function in condition

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript and I have question how to check if variable is not null and if not use it in function ? For instance:

```
var fooNumber = null;

if (!!fooNumber && someFunctionWhichFailWithNull(fooNumber))  { // there I got error because function is called with null;
   // ..
}
```

is some way how to check it in condition and avoid nested conditions? Or there is no another way? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Why would you call a function in a conditional? Catch what you can, when you can: `if (thing) { try { let newthing = callFunction(); ... } catch (e) { ... }}`  etc.

Comment: Instead of a double NOT check, it's much simpler to explicitly check `fooNumber !== null`, just in case `fooNumber` is 0

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans function should return value based on that number and if !!number and returned value are true then fire code in block

Comment: What you have done, shouldn't be calling `someFunctionWhichFailWithNull` have you a running example were this is failing.?   ps.  Doing `if (fooNumber && someFunc...` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to check if the variable is not null and if that's true then call the function. If the variable IS null, it won't call the function.
The following code better represents what you're trying to do:

```
var fooNumber = null;
if (fooNumber !== null) {
    someFunctionWhichFailWithNull(fooNumber);
}
```

Comment: I know about that solution but I wanted to avoid it. someFunctionWhichFailWithNull returns value based on that number and if !!number and returned value are true then fire code in block

Answer (score 1):

This is something that I often used:

```
function(someNumber) {
   //check if someNumber usable
   if(String(someNumber).length > 0 && Number.isInteger(someNumber)) {
     // do something
   } else {
     return false; // or something you want to catch
  }
}
```